# API/Library for accessing pre-defined TypeScript globals

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to access an officially-sourced listing of the pre-defined globals or global constructs of TypeScript, ranging from `Uint32ArrayConstructor` to `Pick`, etc.

A simple search of the repo didn't turn up instances of `Uint32ArrayConstructor`, but I see in the typescript release package that there are declaration files including ones which include this interface.

I was wondering, however, if there is some TypeScript API or third-party library which allows easy introspection on these types from JavaScript (rather than having to parse the files individually). I just need a listing of the available globals as strings.

I'm guessing for what I guess would be more syntactical vocabulary like `Pick` or `T`, these might not have a central listing, but these would be nice to have as well.

This is intended for the sake of ensuring `eslint-plugin-jsdoc`'s `no-undefined-types` rule doesn't treat TypeScript's constructs as undefined types.

Comment: Try the TS compiler API?

Comment: Thanks, but in looking at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API , it appears to me to be more for managing data or files already in hand rather than introspecting on all that is available with TS...

Comment: The TS Language Service API seems more promising. You could make a dummy server and feed it some dummy code (like `type T =`), then tell it to suggest completions (which will include global types).